# How to color textbox based on the value of another textbox?

Tags: vba

I have a userform being populated by a series of dependent comboboxes using a for loop to cycle through the corresponding cells of the selection made from the comboboxes and filling in the corresponding texboxes.

This is all working.

I want to color the textboxes based on a limit specified in another textbox.

Basically it looks as follows

User Form Image
[image]

I'm using a case statement to specify my range based on the number in the Limit textbox using Green, orange and red for 0, anything within the limit indicated, and anything above. They are sometimes coloring incorrectly.

Form - Working
[image]

Form - Not Working
[image]

```
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
    Select Case TextBox5.Value
        Case 0: TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(14, 237, 59)
        Case 1 To TextBox6.Value: TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(237, 181, 14)
        Case Else: TextBox5.BackColor = RGB(250, 0, 12)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox8_Change()
    Select Case TextBox7.Value
        Case 0: TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(14, 237, 59)
        Case 1 To TextBox8.Value: TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(237, 181, 14)
        Case Else: TextBox7.BackColor = RGB(250, 0, 12)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox10_Change()
    Select Case TextBox9.Value
        Case 0: TextBox9.BackColor = RGB(14, 237, 59)
        Case 1 To TextBox10.Value: TextBox9.BackColor = RGB(237, 181, 14)
        Case Else: TextBox9.BackColor = RGB(250, 0, 12)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
    Select Case TextBox11.Value
        Case 0: TextBox11.BackColor = RGB(14, 237, 59)
        Case 1 To TextBox12.Value: TextBox11.BackColor = RGB(237, 181, 14)
        Case Else: TextBox11.BackColor = RGB(250, 0, 12)
    End Select
End Sub
```

I added the case statements to the Limit textbox change subs as these are filled after the textboxes above.

When I use F8 to cycle through the code, the textbox values are filling correctly.